# Can you use BlocListener and BlocBuilder of different Bloc types in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have two BLoCs and need to listen for state changes from one in order to add events to the other and build the UI.

I think it's easier to explain in code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<BlocA>(
      create: (context) => BlocA(),  <------ Create BlocA
      child: BlocProvider<BlocB>(
        create: (context) => BlocB(),  <---- Create BlocB
    
        child: BlocListener<BlocA, StateA>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is StateA) {
              context.read<BlocB>().add(EventB()); <--- When BlocA is ready, add EventB to BlocB
            }
          },
          child: BlocBuilder<BlocB, StateB>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is StateBInitial) {
                return Container(color: Colors.yellow); <-- shows initial as expected
              }
              if (state is StateBSuccess) {
                return Container(color: Colors.green); <-- success is never triggered
              }
              return Container(color: Colors.red);
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the example above I create 2 BLoCs, BlocA and BlocB.
I add them in providers and then create a BlocListener that listen for BlocA changes and add events to BlocB.

The problem is that the BlocBuilder never triggers after the initial state.
I can see in debugging that the Event added by the the BlocListener is registered and data is fetched and yielded, but the BlocBuilder never triggers even though the state has changed.

It is as if the BlocListener is calling a different BlocB.

Comment: can you please add your state object? it can be caused by immutability issues. @Joel Broström

Comment: Maybe your bloc accepts your state but not yields if it is not changed since last event. This can happen if it is not immutable or you forget to add property to `props` if you are using Equatable

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunately the code is gone. 
I can assure the props were all set. 
I had issues with it before and checked it multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm right, you are trying to make communication with two blocs?

There is a really well-explained video tutorial about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ricBLKHeubM

Comment: Yes. When one bloc returns a state the other should add an event. It's a one way flow of communication and it only happens once. Just like my interactions on a typical night out :D